# SQL Replication from Win CE device to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-ce, sql-server-ce, merge-replication

I have a Windows CE device that I'd like to replicate data to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I understand the basics of replication and I need to use MSDN's "Two-Server Topology". Where there is an IIS box and a separate SQL Server box.

I have replication and a publication set up on the SQL database. Also, on the IIS box I created a virtual directory and via UNC have the physical folder on the database box. Now I'm at the point of configuring the IIS box.

According to the "Two-Server Topology" I don't need SQL Server installed on the IIS box. Just the SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 Tools. However, when I run the setup for the CE tools installation, it fails stating the Replication Components are not installed. After investigating it seems the only way to install Replication Components is via a SQL Server installation.

Am I missing something? Can I have the IIS box be standalone without SQL Server installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the Client Connectivity Components from the SQL Server Media, and make sure to install the latest SQL Server Compact Server Tools: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/06/walkthrough-configuring-merge.html

Comment: When I run the install for the SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Server Tools, it fails the system configuration check saying "You must first install the Replication Components for SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008. This is where I'm having the issue. So far the only way I've found to install the Replication Components is via a SQL Server install. I dont want a full SQL install on the IIS box.

Comment: It appears the issue here is that the IIS box is on a hosted server I do not have physical access to.  I'll have to get someone at the host to install the Replication Components via the SQL install disc:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172376.aspx

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my answer, they are required.